# Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to coding so I can not understand and solve this problem if you want please help me.

C:\projects\assignment-11\spice-warehouse-server\node_modules\bson\lib\error.js:41
var _this = _super.call(this, message) || this;
^

BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
at new BSONTypeError (C:\projects\assignment-11\spice-warehouse-server\node_modules\bson\lib\error.js:41:28)
at new ObjectId (C:\projects\assignment-11\spice-warehouse-server\node_modules\bson\lib\objectid.js:66:23)
at ObjectId (C:\projects\assignment-11\spice-warehouse-server\node_modules\bson\lib\objectid.js:26:20)
at C:\projects\assignment-11\spice-warehouse-server\index.js:38:33
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\projects\assignment-11\spice-warehouse-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\projects\assignment-11\spice-warehouse-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\projects\assignment-11\spice-warehouse-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\projects\assignment-11\spice-warehouse-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\projects\assignment-11\spice-warehouse-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:22
at param (C:\projects\assignment-11\spice-warehouse-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:367:14)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an issue related to `react-router`. What is the code that caused this result? Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to provide a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ID is not being sent. You can try this way:

```js
const query = { _id: ObjectId('yourid') };
```

Comment: I solve this problem a few days ago but your answer helped me to identify the problem. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be related to express.js related, so if this is your problem then you first turn off your server pressing by ctrl + c then turn it on again, then you go to your UI and hit reload then it will work properly.